# C# If(textbox.text=number) error

Tags: c#, if-statement, textbox, implicit-conversion

I making a quiz in which users would have to enter a number (e.g. 4) into a `TextBox` then the program would check if the number entered is correct. Unfortunately, I'm having some trouble with this part of the code.

So currently I have this code:

```
if(textbox1.Text=4)
```

but the `4` is underlined with the error message:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'.

Can I trouble you all to help me find out what's wrong with my code? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Thank you all so much for you valuable help! My question is answered! Thanks again!

Comment: Please mark your favorite answer as solution, so this topic can be closed

Comment: You can avoid having to handle user input like this by providing him variants of answers with correct answer and few incorrect ones. E.g. question `"2+2=?"` and 3 buttons: `3`, `4` and `5`.

Comment: @Sinatr totally agree, this is such a simple question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `textbox1.Text` is of type `string`, you have to *parse*:

```
   int answer;

   //  TryParse - the value entered can be treated as a valid integer 
   //  answer == correctAnswer - the answer provided is a correct one 
   if (int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out answer) && answer == correctAnswer) {
     ...
   }
```

Please, notice that the implementation tolerates *leading* and *traling* spaces (typical problem in quizes): if user happens to input `"4 "` (trailing space) the answer will be *accepted* providing that `correctAnswer == 4`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(textbox1.Text == Convert.ToString(4))
```

or

```
if(textbox1.Text == "4")
```

Comment: must use `==` to compare

Comment: if( textbox1.Text == Convert.ToString(4) )

Comment: this implementation can be too rigid: imaging that user input `"4 "` (please, notice *trailing space*)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare a `string` with an `int`.

You need to use `if(textbox1.text == "4")`

also note the double `==` for comparisons

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse to int

```
if(Int32.Parse(textbox1.Text) == 4)
```

Comment: must use `==` to compare

Comment: @msanz yes changed

Comment: If user enters not a number app will crash

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a `string` (textbox1.Text) with an `integer` (4). To make this work you have to compare same data types. Some options:

```
if(textbox1.Text == "4")
```

or

```
if(textbox1.Text == 4.ToString())
```

or

```
if(int.Parse(textbox1.Text) == 4)
```

NOTE: In the last option you can get an exception if the text in the `textbox` is not a number. So if you want to convert to integer than I would suggest:

```
int guessedNumber; 
Int32.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out guessedNumber);
if(guessedNumber == 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` property is of type `string` and 4 is an `int` so the comparison results in a compile time error.

Use the following code to perform the check.

```
if (int.Parse(textbox1.Text) == 4)
{
    // do something
}
```

If you're unsure whether the user is going to provide the input correctly or if you haven't set any validations on the model, then you should parse the input and then check whether the user entered 4. Here's the rextester [link](http://rextester.com/VFCFU48723)

```
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

using System;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = "hello 4";
            // var input = "4";
            int number;
            var isNumber = int.TryParse(input, out number);
            if (isNumber)
            {
                if (number == 4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The Number is 4");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The Number isn't 4");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(textbox1.Text == "4")
{
//Do Something
}
```

One way or another, you have to make sure both values are to make sure you are comparing two values "==" (not "=", unless u want to change the value) and that both values are same data type